# Is it a zero or one char wildcard in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm looking for zero or one char wildcard, cause "_" is one char, and "%" is zero or more chars. So is there a zero or one char wildcard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not in `LIKE`.  But there is using regular expressions -- it is the `?` modifier.  For instance, for 0 or 1 characters between A and C:

```
where col regexp 'A.?B'
```